# How get part of string using PHP

Tags: php, string

String:

```
$local = "/c/xampp/htdocs/path/storage/public/*"
```

How explode above string and get only the part after `/path`?

Something like this

```
getPublicPart( $local ) // @return string "/storage/public/*"
```

Comment: what makes `\path\` special in this case? Did you want the actual physical path, or the logical one according to the webserver?

Comment: that's not what programmers would commonly call the "absolute path" its not clear why this particular piece of the path is defined

Comment: You need to tell us why do you want /path? It may be a wrong path also :D

Comment: i just want to response the part after '/path' to client

Answer (score 1, accepted):

best i can do based on information provided

```
<?php
$absolute = "/c/xampp/htdocs/path/storage/public/*";


function getPublicPart($path){
  $x=explode('path',$path);
return $x[1];
}

 echo  getPublicPart( $absolute ); // @return string "/storage/public/*"
```

demo:http://codepad.viper-7.com/EXU7Q5

plan 2

remove everything before a known point:

```
 function getPublicPart($path){
    return strstr($path, 'storage'); 
}
echo  getPublicPart( $absolute );
```

demo: http://codepad.viper-7.com/YtAorb

Comment: considering `path` not a real name, how explode using `\storage` to reference?

Comment: @AlexandreThebaldi my plan 2 answers this (i think)

Answer (score 1):

[`strstr()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strstr.php) will do this:

```
    $absolute = "/c/xampp/htdocs/path/storage/public/*";
    function getPublicPath($str,$needle = 'path/')
    {
        return str_replace($needle, '', strstr($str, $needle));
    }
    echo getPublicPath($absolute);
```

Answer (score 1):

You could also use some very basic regex to get the info you need:

```
<?php

$absolute = "/c/xampp/htdocs/path/storage/public/*";

function getPublicPath($str){
    $pattern = "%path/(.*)%";

    preg_match($pattern, $str, $match);

    return $match[1];
}

echo getPublicPath($absolute);

?>
```